# Breaking variables out of Script scope to be accessible in a console session

Tags: powershell, scope

For debugging purposes I was wondering if there was a way to have variables in the "Script" scope be accessible in the console in which the script is executed.

This is so I could run a script I'm testing in a console and after the script runs having access to $Some_Var_Defined_In_The_Script.

Is this possible? I would only want it for debugging purposes of course so I'm looking for a switch I could turn on and off.

Comment: When I do stuff like debugging, I usually run my code in the PS ISE and put in a breaking point on the line I want it to stop with F9. After hitting Play it stops there and the variables until that point are usable in the console.

Comment: Yeah that's an advantage of the ISE. I reallly prefer vim though. I wonder if there is a way to use breakpoints sans ISE.

Comment: I see.. I think you need to consider putting the breakpoint in your script manually and then it will stop there. As described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849917.aspx)

Comment: call `set-psdebug -trace 2` before your script isn't suffisant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that can be controlled by a switch parameter, you can use a nested prompt:

```
$test = {
param ([switch]$debug = $false)

  $x = Get-Process
  if ($debug) {$host.EnterNestedPrompt()}
}

&test -debug
```

This will drop you into a nested prompt where all the variables will be available to examine.  Enter 'Exit' to return from the nested prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the script from the shell like this:

. .\myscript.ps1

The variables should be available after its completed.